# Set wallpaper in nemo file manager

Tags: nautilus, desktop-background, nemo

I replaced nautilus with nemo file manager, i like nemo much more, but i dont know how to set wallpaper in nemo. If i go to images and **right click on image**, then select "**Set as wallpaper**" nothing happens...

Answer (score 2):

Set Nemo as the default file manager

1. To prevent Nautilus from handling the desktop icons (and use Nemo instead), `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false`
2. Set Nemo as the default file manager (replacing Nautilus) `xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search`

Tested using `Nemo 2.8.7` on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`